# How can I use delegate object as member params in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, delegates

```kotlin
class Test : IPlayer by VideoPlayerHelper() as mPlayer {

    fun startTest() {
        mPlayer.start()
    }
}
```

There is syntax error in mPlayer
How can I use mPlayer as member param?

Comment: You could use: `class Test(val mPlayer: IPlayer = VideoPlayerHelper()) : IPlayer by mPlayer`